# Dynamic filter - Coding JQuery effectively

Tags: jquery

Each time a user creates a new category field a new id for the field is created

category_advert

```
#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advert_id
#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advert_id
#userj_requiredskills_attributes_2_category_advert_id
```

category_advertskill

```
#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advertskill_id
#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advertskill_id
#userj_requiredskills_attributes_2_category_advertskill_id
```

> could one kindly advise me how to code my JQuery effectively, so no
>   matter what the id is the code works - many thanks

html.erb

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_advert_id, CategoryAdvert.order(:name), :id, :name, {},  {class: 'category_advert'}  %>
  <%= f.grouped_collection_select :category_advertskill_id, CategoryAdvert.order(:name), :category_advertskills, :name, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select a category"}, {class: "category_advertskill"} %>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var category_advertskills;
  category_advertskills = $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advertskill_id').html();
  return $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advert_id').change(function() {
    var category_advert, escaped_category_advert, options;
    category_advert = $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advert_id :selected').text();
    escaped_category_advert = category_advert.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(category_advertskills).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_category_advert + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advertskill_id').html(options);
      return $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advertskill_id').parent().show();
    } else {
      $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advertskill_id').empty();
      return $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_0_category_advertskill_id').parent().hide();
    }
  });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
  var category_advertskills;
  category_advertskills = $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advertskill_id').html();
  return $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_01category_advert_id').change(function() {
    var category_advert, escaped_category_advert, options;
    category_advert = $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advert_id :selected').text();
    escaped_category_advert = category_advert.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    options = $(category_advertskills).filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_category_advert + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advertskill_id').html(options);
      return $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advertskill_id').parent().show();
    } else {
      $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advertskill_id').empty();
      return $('#userj_requiredskills_attributes_1_category_advertskill_id').parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Share you html code and what you want ?

Comment: Start by using variables to hold those duplicate *mile-long* selectors instead of doing he same selector over and over. `$(this)` inside the `change` event will also be the same element you keep referencing. You can then just use a `starts-with` selector for the matches.

Answer (score 1):

Start by using variables to hold those duplicate *mile-long* selectors instead of doing the same selector over and over. `$(this)` inside the `change` event will also be the same element you keep referencing. You can then just use a `starts-with` selector for the matches.

e.g. something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var category_advertskills = $('[id^="userj_requiredskills_attributes_"]');
  category_advertskills.change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var category_advert = $this.find(':selected').text();
    var escaped_category_advert = category_advert.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1');
    var options = category_advertskills.filter("optgroup[label='" + escaped_category_advert + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      $this.html(options);
      $this.parent().show();
    } else {
      $this.empty();
      $this.parent().hide();
    }
  });
});
```

You also seem to have some unwanted returns that will not be used in a DOM ready handler.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class for all of the categories and use data attributes for the type and ID

```
 <div class="requiredskill" data-user="userj" data-type="advertskill">blah</div>
```

And then from jquery, lookup elements with that class and check the data attribute.

```
$(".requiredskill")[0].data("user"); //userj
```

You can match specific data values in a selector like so:

```
$(".requiredskill[data-user=userj][data-type=advertskill]")
```